# LIBGDX ModelInstance Global Rotation

Tags: 3d, rotation, libgdx, global, axis

I am currently working on a project in libgdx and I have a problem with the rotation of a modelInstance object. I rotate the modelInstance until it's -90 degrees on the x-axis. The second time that I rotate for 45 degrees on the z-axis, the modelInstance object instead use the world's y-axis. I know that it is using its rotation axis and not the world axis. What will be the code for rotating the transformed modelInstance correctly? Here is part of the source code that I am struggling to solve for hours:

```
    if (count == 0 && RotationValues.ball[0] > -90) {
                    RotationValues.ball[0] -= 1;

                    Objects.Ball.modelInstance.transform.rotate(1, 0, 0, -1);

    else if (count == 2 && RotationValues.ball[2] < 45) {
                    RotationValues.ball[2] += 1;                        

                    Objects.Ball.modelInstance.transform.rotate(0, 0, 1, -1);
```

I checked the same question on google but he was using a matrix:

> https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74377/matrix-rotation-wrong-orientation-libgdx

I made some improvised codes to work on it but it didn't work so I end up asking here.